# TASM pointing to char or position

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I have a section of code that looks like this:

```
copy_line PROC near
    push si
    mov currentline_offset, 0

copy_line_copy:
    mov ax, buffer_len
    cmp buffer_offset, ax
    jl copy_line_tesk

    mov buffer_offset, 0
    mov bx, sourceFHandle
    mov dx, offset buffer       ; address of buffer in dx
    mov cx, len                 ; kiek baitu nuskaitysim
    mov ah, 3fh             ; function 3Fh - read from file
    int 21h
    ;jc error
    cmp ax, 0
    je copy_line_end
    mov buffer_len, ax

copy_line_tesk:
        mov si, offset buffer
    add si, buffer_offset
    mov ax, ds:[si]

    mov si, offset currentline
    add si, currentline_offset
    mov byte ptr ds:[si], al

    inc currentline_offset
    inc buffer_offset
    cmp ax, 13
    jne copy_line_copy

copy_line_end:
    pop si
    ret
copy_line ENDP
```

The idea is to read a line, point a pointer to the end of the line, work with the information (something to be added) and then output one of two results (also to be added). Then it reads the next line and repeats.

I have 2 questions about this:
1) Do the pointers point to the symbol, or the number that the position is? (I.e. If the line is, say, "Aerosmith", do the pointers point at "A" and "H" or "1" and "9"?
2) How do I compare the two pointers towards what the don't point at (I.e. If they're pointing at "A" and "H", how do I compare their positions relative to each other? Or, if they're pointing at "1" and "9", how do I compare the characters themselves?)

I thank you for the help.

Comment: _"the pointers"_. Please specify exactly what you mean by this. Which instruction(s) are you referring to?

Comment: Referring to currentline and currentline_offset, as those, if I'm not mistaken, point to the first and last characters of the line which I'm going to want to compare.

Comment: `currentline` represents an address of your buffer. So it points to the first character. `currentline_offset` also represents an address, of a number that represents how far along in the buffer the algorithm has gotten. It doesn't point to the buffer at all, and it changes each time through the loop. `buffer_offset` has an issue: it's not initialized the first time it's used.